Help identifying this french movie from 90s or 2000s
There are 3-4 guys chasing each other. They are driving through a desert in Africa to a seaside, carrying a large sum of money stolen from a plane. One of them is a pilot. One of trucks is a tow truck and one of trucks is a large cistern (mack probably). They go through a tunnel where rims cut tires and through a minefield. There is an Arab girl an mines in a sea too. It is like 90s or 2000s movie.
can't recall the name but i would like to see it again.


Could be Cent mille dollars au soleil (1964) aka ''Greed in the Sun''.

Rocco (Jean-Paul Belmondo) and his female accomplice, Angèle
  (Anne-Maire Coffinet) hijack a truck from a trucking company in the
  Saharan desert. The head of the trucking company, Castigliano (Gert
  Frobe, Goldfinger) hires Rocco’s friend, Hervé (Lino Ventura) and a
  newly employed German, Hans (Reginald Kernan) to go after him and
  bring the back the valuable goods. After the two run into some trouble
  Castigliano sends a second truck driven by Mitch (Bernard Blier) and
  Khenouche (Doudou Babet). --- Synopsis from OliveFilms

Watch a clip/trailer. There's also a colourised version, which is probably what you saw. One more clip in colour.
------------------------EDIT-------------------------

Here's a better bet: Sueurs (2002) :-)
Some stills, more details and here's the trailer.

Nah, it sounds like it but its a 60s movie. maybe i saw a remake though.

I've added what I think is the right movie. Take a look :-)

Feel free to post your new edit as a separate answer, to give people (and the asker) the chance to judge them individually.

Ha! That's it! Thanks! My rep is to low to +1 your answer.
